# How to animate UIView from top to bottom and vice versa?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview

I'm trying to animate UIImageView from top to bottom and vice versa.
I tried the code:

Previous value was(`y == 0`):

```
laserImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0.0, width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
```

and want to animate it to `500.0`:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, delay: 0.2, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
    laserImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 500.0, width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
}) { (finished) in
    if finished {
        // Repeat animation from bottom to top
    }
}
```

but when I run my app the UIImageView appears at the last point(`y == 500`) without any animation, like the initial position was `500.0` but not `0.0`.

I do not understand why animation does not work. Any idea?

Comment: Where you have added this animation code. In viewDidLoad ?

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava yes, in `viewDidLoad`. I always called it there =/

Comment: Using auto layout ?

Comment: @KumarKL no, I added everything in code

Comment: And where you set this `laserImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0.0, width: 300.0, height: 300.0)` . Before animation Code?

Comment: Try putting it in `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava right before `UIView.animation` I create the UIImageView and set its initial position

Comment: Add both the lines animation plus setting the frame in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: One way to do so is take a IBOutlet of top constraint of view which you want to animate and update the value of constraint using the below method.- (IBAction)animateButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    [UIView transitionWithView:_topView duration:0.8 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
        _headerViewTopConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.height - 20;
         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}

Comment: You can take Top or Bottom constraint of that view and accordingly that constraint you can move your view up,down

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava @Sweeper adding the code in `viewillAppear` solved the problem

Comment: how to close the question? Thanks for your comments! They helped me a lot!

Comment: @J.Doe Don't close it. It may help others in future

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let laserImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0.0, width: 300.0, height: 300.0))



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    laserImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    self.view.addSubview(laserImageView)
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    bottom()


}

func bottom()  {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, delay: 0.2, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
        self.laserImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 500.0, width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
    }) { (finished) in
        if finished {
            // Repeat animation from bottom to top
            self.Up()
        }
    }
}

func Up()  {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, delay: 0.2, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
        self.laserImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.laserImageView.bounds.origin.y, width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
    }) { (finished) in
        if finished {
            // Repeat animation to bottom to top
            self.bottom()
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I figured out more elegant solution for that ;)

Answer (score -2):

One way to do so is take a IBOutlet of top constraint of view which you want to animate and update the value of constraint using the below method:-

```
- (IBAction)animateButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    [UIView transitionWithView:_topView duration:0.8 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
        _headerViewTopConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.height - 20;
         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}
```

[image]

Comment: The questioner is not using Interface Builder.

Comment: So you need to mention it while asking the question. and don't need to down vote as it will definitely solve your purpose.

Comment: @moritz Thanks bro but if the question is not complete then how can a person give him an exact answer. Beside down vote he needs to ask to post an answer for code as well.

Comment: @Moritz okey bro but think a bit if the question is not for interface builder or code user feel free to post an answer in any way so i choose the interface what's wrong with the answer. Yes I am wrong at the place language selection as it was posted for a swift tag beside objective c.

Answer (score -3):

For those who wants to do it using code inspite of interface builder can use below answer:-

```
__weak FirstViewController *weakSelf = self;
[UIView transitionWithView:_topView duration:0.4 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    //
    _topView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, _topView.frame.size.width, _topView.frame.size.height);
    [weakSelf.view layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //
}];
```

**Please try to post complete question inspite of downvoting the answer :) Thanks**

Comment: The question has been tagged with Swift, what's the point of posting an Objective-C answer?

Comment: What is the point in posting 2 answers here. Just update your answer or merge both the answers.

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava I have posted to answer 1 for the interface builder and another for the code.

Comment: '@IBAction func animateMeButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.transition(with: topView, duration: 0.4, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.topView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: self.topView.frame.size.width, height: self.topView.frame.size.height)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded();
        }) { (isFinished) in
        }
    }'

Comment: @AnupamGupta Just write like this -- 1st approach write code and then 2nd approach -- your interface builder. Keep as simple as possible. And don't post two answers for the same question. You have to be very simple here.